# _ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED and _ATL_FREE_THREADED conflict

Tags: c++, com, thread-safety

I am developing on an existing C++ COM DLL with VS2008.

the compiler says:
"More than one global threading model defined"

in my StdAfx.h i got this define:
`#define _ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED`

I initialize COM with this:
`CoInitialize(NULL);`

but i can't find a define for _ATL_FREE_THREADED. the compiler warning indicates that both must be defined somewhere. but i don't know where to find the _ATL_FREE_THREADED.

any ideas why i get the compiler msg?

thanks juergen

Answer (score 0):

Those symbols are defined inside `atlbase.h` and `atldef.h` which reside along with other ATL headers - you can look there and see that there's some simple logic for detecting whether one of those symbols has bee set already and setting a default one.

Comment: thanks for the hint. but how can I avoid getting this warning?

Comment: @juergen: Obviously you have that symbol defined at inappropriate time in your code. The right way to do that is to first define the symbol, then include ATL characters.

Answer (score 0):

it does sound like you code somewhere defines _ATL_FREE_THREADED.  You could sprinkle...

```
#ifdef _ATL_FREE_THREADED
#pragma message ("hi")
#endif
```

... between various include files to see if you can find the one that defines that macro.  Before you do that though, have you checked to make sure it's not defined in the project properties (both at project and at cpp file levels)?